# elasticsearch search for products indice but sort by the prices indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indices: `products` and `prices`. `products` has reference `price_id`. Yes, one price can have many products.

the `prices` updates frequently and the `products` is about 1M and is increasing.

just like other ecommerce sites, we want to allow search product title and sort by the list_price/sale_price.

but from what I know, elasticsearch doesn't support join-like search.

Answer (score 0):

You can search product title from `products`.Then use the `price_id` to search list_price/sale_price from `prices`.Finally sort the results in the program.